# A limit $\rightarrow (-1,3)$ which equals $- \infty$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find a multivariable limit $\rightarrow (-1,3)$ which equals $- \infty$. I tried many limits, but I fail to find one.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x,y) = -\frac{1}{|x+1|}$$

You should be able to convince yourself this works.

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't $y$ used anywhere.

Comment: No reason it needs to be. $f$ is still a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. It is simpler to not include $y$, if you really wanted to, you could define $f(x,y) = - \frac{y}{|x+1|}$, but again not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: If your question has been resolved, please click the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: I will, but I can do it only after 10 minutes after submitting question.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y)=\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2-10}$$